# Why I don't get import suggestions with babeljs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs, yarn-workspaces

I'm using babel-env with vscode and yarn workspaces and when I'm loading a package (after compiling).

I don't get any suggestion for imports autocomplete..

My project structure:

```
|--packages
| |--common
|    |--src
|    |--dist
|    |--.babelrc
| |--server
|    |--src
|    |--dist
|    |--.babelrc
| |--web(create-react-app default settings)
```

babelrc setting:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

build command:

```
rm -rf dist && babel ./src --out-dir dist --copy-files
```

example of import usage:

```
import { validation, functions } from "@project/common";
```

Then when I'm typing for exmaple `validation.inputs` I'm not getting any suggestions..

Maybe I need to ad some babel extensions, I searched in the docs but found nothing.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on package.json i added :

```
  "types": "./index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "index.d.ts"
  ],
```

and on common root folder i added the file : "index.d.ts" which containts

```
export { default } from "./src/index";
export * from "./src/index";
```

I dont know if you need to do that this way but it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try adding es6 capabilities to your workspace. So in your `jsconfig.json` add this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```